# script not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code to add item in the cart working fine in Chrome, Firefox but not working in the IE8, i m taking those to cart who has been checked and for this i have done in the following way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var product_arr=new Array();
    jQuery('.ProceedToCheckout').click(function(){
        var p1 = document.getElementById('product1').checked;
        var p2 = document.getElementById('product2').checked;
        var p3 = document.getElementById('product3').checked;
        var p4 = document.getElementById('product4').checked;

        if(p1){
        var pid1 = jQuery('#product1').val();
        product_arr.push(pid1);
    }
        if(p2){
        var pid2 = jQuery('#product2').val();
        product_arr.push(pid2);
        }
        if(p3){
        var pid3 = jQuery('#product3').val();
        product_arr.push(pid3);
        }
        if(p4){
        var pid4 = jQuery('#product4').val();
        product_arr.push(pid4);
        } 
        var i=0;
        jQuery('.cart_iframe_1').attr('src','http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id='+product_arr[0]);
        console.log('http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id='+product_arr[i]);
        i++;
    var t=setInterval(function(){
            if(i<product_arr.length ){ 
                jQuery('.cart_iframe_1').attr('src','http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id='+product_arr[i]);
                console.log('http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id='+product_arr[i]);
                i++;
            }
        else{
        clearInterval(t); 
        document.location.href="http://www.merimobiles.com/checkout.php";   
        }   
           },5000);
     });
});
```

Comment: can you show us code where you declared your jquery/javascript ?

Comment: use the console in developer toolbar (F12) to see the error

Comment: im calling the scriopt on iframe
<div style="">
    <iframe class="cart_iframe_1" style="" src="http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=9978" frameborder="0" ></iframe> 
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

console.log() may be a problem. Remove it or check if defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   alert('somevalue');
});
```

If its not alert means there is problem to define jquery.

Also try `console bar` where you can check your `jquery` is load or not for that page.

Comment: i check it and found that iframe executes but nothing added in the cart i think  the scriptfrom setInterval() does not working

Answer (score 0):

also I think that you should declare "t" variable globally for whole script. Sometimes ClearInterval may not work if "t" is local